# How do I specify this filename to git?

Tags: git, special-characters

According to Git, the letter Å apparently isn't the letter Å. **How do I work with this?**

```
$ git config core.quotepath false

$ git status
On branch swift2
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/swift_2.0-tester' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    deleted:    Åka Strax.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
    deleted:    Åka Strax.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata
    deleted:    Åka StraxTests/A_ka_StraxTests.swift
    deleted:    Åka StraxTests/Info.plist

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    deleted:    Åka Strax.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
    deleted:    Åka StraxTests/Info.plist
    deleted:    NärliggandeHållplatser.swift


$ git rm --cached "Åka StraxTests/Info.plist"
fatal: pathspec 'Åka StraxTests/Info.plist' did not match any files


$ git config core.quotePath true

$ git status
On branch swift2
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/swift_2.0-tester' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)
Changes to be committed:
  (use "git reset HEAD <file>..." to unstage)

    deleted:    "\303\205ka Strax.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj"
    deleted:    "\303\205ka Strax.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/contents.xcworkspacedata"
    deleted:    "\303\205ka StraxTests/A_ka_StraxTests.swift"
    deleted:    "\303\205ka StraxTests/Info.plist"

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    deleted:    "A\314\212ka Strax.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj"
    deleted:    "A\314\212ka StraxTests/Info.plist"
    deleted:    "Na\314\210rliggandeHa\314\212llplatser.swift"
```

I could successfully add changes to the index when `Å` = `\303\205`, but not for filenames where Å = `A\314\212`. Any regex I use to match any other letter will unvariably also match other files.

How do I explicitly specify the filenames of these unstaged changes? E.g. can I input the file name with escaped characters just like git outputs them, and if not: how am I supposed to tell git which file I'm referring to?

I don't know if, or why, git expects me to type things in some specific encoding (?!), but that's not how I usually type.

Update: OS X 10.10.4, bash, HFS+ (bad news?)

Comment: One problem I see here is that you are putting the wildcard character, `*`, inside quotes.  Consider the output of `ls *` vs `ls "*"` and you'll see the problem.

Comment: I knew someone would mention it ;) so just to be sure I tried it: Å* (without quotes) matches zero files.

Comment: Consider updating your question to reflect the exact command you used as well as the output.  Putting the wildcard in quotes is simply wrong, so obviously people will focus on that.

Comment: Also, git haven't had any problems with wildcats inside quotes AFAIR

Comment: @larsks But I would be interested in a source that says git doesn't accept wildcards inside quotes, because it has worked as expected every time I've tried it.

Comment: @larsks Updated. No more wildcards.

Comment: What operating system are you using? Filesystem? Shell?

Comment: I'm in the process of renaming all files to ascii only, because I read that git and HFS don't seem to play well together. That's when the problem arose that I can't even untrack the old files :-/

Comment: You can use `git add -u` to add all known files that has been changed (in this case deleted from index, I know, feels weird to use "add" when staging a removed file)

Comment: @joran Thank you, I'll try it at the next opportunity